# Aliasing the find command tcsh

Tags: escaping, command-line-arguments, alias, tcsh

I'm trying to make an alias for the find command to search recursively within the directory for a string in any part of the filename in tcsh so that I can shrink

```
find . -name "*foo*"
```

down to this

```
fnd foo
```

Unfortunately I'm getting no matches, or the incorrect number of matches, with the alias below:

```
 alias fnd find . -name \"\*\!:1\*\"
```

I don't know if I'm escaping the ", *, and ! correctly with the backslash. When I do `Ctrl+x ?` to expand the alias, I get `find . -name \"*!:1*\"` if that helps at all. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this `alias fnd 'find . -name "*\!:1**"'`